# QGIS raster image transparency, NO DATA value for all raster images?

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity, nodata

I'm working with sets of aerial images in QGIS which are geocoded including orientation i.e. rotated.

After loading images QGIS draws a black box around each image that extends from the far west to far east pixel and from the far north to far south pixel. Within this black box lays the actual image in it's correct orientation.

To get rid of this black box I currently enter 0 in Layer Properties / Transparency / Additional NODATA value but the change has to be made on every single image. Unfortunately the transparency setting is not part of the Style definition and therefore cannot be copied from one to all other raster layers / images.

Is there better way to add a global NODATA value to all raster data in current workspace?

Raster Calculator won't work as there are no NODATA areas in the actual image files.

Comment: One way to do it would be to edit the qgis file in a text editor.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at **VRTs** ([Virtual Rasters](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html)).

You can build these in QGIS, using **Raster > Miscellaneous > Build virtual raster (Catalog)**, or directly on the command line using **gdalbuildvrt**

VRTs are small XML files which stitch together lots of rasters into one, "big" virtual raster which can be loaded and processed as if it was a single raster.

If you set the **sourcenodata** to "0 0 0" (assuming 3 bands, r,g,b) it should set pixels to transparent by setting the nodata value to 0. You probably want settings to look something like this:-

[image: vrt settings for nodata values]

I don't have any batches of aerial imagery to hand to test this, but it should allow you to merge all your images and set a single NODATA value for all of them across multiple bands.

I tried this by creating a VRT from a single aerial raster (without a nodata value) and it had the desired effect of setting nodata to 0, and the empty areas to transparent, so it's worth a try.

Also tried this from the Processing/GDAL menu in QGIS 2.16.3, and this option was missing. So use the old-style menu option or the command line to try this out.

Comment: oh, that's a shame :( The image I tried wasn't rotated (well, not in the geotranform anyway). Wasn't aware of that limitation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to VRT. Unfortunately gdalbuildvrt doesn't seem to like rotated images: `Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support rotated geo transforms. Skipping D:/Herbst 2016/Stenden/out_8bit/28_0092.tif`

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is in the qgs file as [suggested by Alexandre Neto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213712/qgis-raster-image-transparency-no-data-value-for-all-raster-images#comment327178_213712)

for all raster files replace

```
<noData>
    <noDataList bandNo="1" useSrcNoData="0"/>
    <noDataList bandNo="2" useSrcNoData="0"/>
    <noDataList bandNo="3" useSrcNoData="0"/>
  </noData>
```

with

```
<noData>
    <noDataList bandNo="1" useSrcNoData="0">
      <noDataRange min="0" max="0"/>
    </noDataList>
    <noDataList bandNo="2" useSrcNoData="0">
      <noDataRange min="0" max="0"/>
    </noDataList>
    <noDataList bandNo="3" useSrcNoData="0">
      <noDataRange min="0" max="0"/>
    </noDataList>
  </noData>
```

At least it worked easily for me on a project containing ONLY raster images and using `Replace all`in the editor. Thanks Alexandre!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I find the easiest way to do this using a python script that works on all selected layers

```
for layer in layers:
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    provider.setNoDataValue(1, -9999) # first value is band number   


iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```